# Environment variable only works in windows command prompt when i run it "start in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"

Tags: windows, sublimetext3, command-prompt

I am trying to add the Sublime Text directory to environment variable PATH so I can start Sublime from `cmd` in Windows 7 easily. But, it is not working when I start `cmd` without doing this...

[image]

Opening this shortcut makes all Sublime available in command line...

However if I start `cmd` directly it or by right clicking in a folder and try to start Sublime it says internal error
[image]

My path settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy the text into your question.

Comment: i have pretty much " not recognized as an internal" .... HomePath etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reboot the machine, or log out and back in.  On at least some versions of Windows, the "Open command window here" menu option doesn't check for changes to environment variables that have been made since the user logged on.

This appears to be a bug in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the directory where you installed Sublime to the `PATH` variable. Select **`Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> System`**, click on the **`Advanced`** tab, then click on <kbd>Environment Variables</kbd>. Under **`System Variables`** select **`Path`**, then click <kbd>Edit</kbd>. At the end of the line, add `;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` (make sure you include the semi-colon `;` at the beginning). If Sublime was installed in a different directory (for example, if you are running the portable version), use that one instead. Save everything, restart `cmd`, and `subl` should now work.

Comment: i have done exactly that, subl works when i start cmd from start menu which has start in value set as above. However i start cmd from shortcut that has these values removed it wont work this is trouble some because i usually shift right click the folder i am in and click open cmd here. which doesn't let me specify start as

Comment: see question i added it

Comment: You need to add to the Path under **`System Variables`**, not user variables. I stated that in my answer.

Comment: i forgot to tell i added it in both top one and system variables, i appended the absolute path to folder of sublime in value of PATH